# Angular2: Reload table while uploading large file

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I have a page with table that listed file I uploaded (getting this from the server)
and upload button, once I click upload, it issue GET request from the server to give me the upload status (the server can give feedback)
The problem is that when I upload large file, it will not proceed to the "read status" function.

Here is my part of the code that I am using:

```html
upload() {
    console.log("Clicked upload");
    if(this.file.size > 0) {
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('csv_file', this.file, this.file.name);
        console.log("uploading file:");
        var FileName = this.file.name;
        this.startTimer();
        this._httpRequest.makeFileUpload('csv_upload', formData, FileName)
        .subscribe(MyTests => {
          this.noFile = true;
          this.resetFileName();
          this.ReadData(); <----------- not running this
        },
        () => { 
          console.log("Error sending file") ;
          this.errorLoading = true;
          }
        );
    }
  }
```

of course I cannot call the this.ReadData() before upload begins (read data is GET HTTP request)
id there a way to overcome it?

[image]

Comment: Have you got any errors in console or network tab?

Comment: no error, I assume the issue is that, it cannot execute the ReadData till subscribe is finised

Comment: If it is the case then you should see pending request in network tab of developer tools

Comment: I added picture from the network tab

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing the code order to the following

```js
 upload() {
    console.log("Clicked upload");
    if(this.file.size > 0) {
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('csv_file', this.file, this.file.name);
        var FileName = this.file.name;
        this._httpRequest.makeFileUpload('csv_upload', formData, FileName)
        .subscribe(MyTests => {
          this.isLoading=false;
          this.noFile = true;
          this.resetFileName();
         },
           () => { 
          this.errorLoading = true;
          this.isLoading=false;
         }
        );
         this.startTimer();
         this.ReadData();
    }
  }
```